# python part of code not being accessed(hangman game)

Tags: python, list

I was writing a code for hangman and as the main working of the game i used the following code:

```
    def game_start(game_wordlist,game_words,word):
    wrong=10
    tag=0
    cnt=0
    wrongli=[]
    while wrong>0:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("At any point in time enter menu to return to menu.")
        print("-"*45)
        print(wrongli)
        print("-"*45)
        li='-'*len(word)
        print(li)
        user_letter=raw_input(">")
        list1=list(li)
        if (not user_letter in wrongli) and (not user_letter in li):
            tag=0
            cnt=0
            x=len(word)
            while cnt<x:
                if user_letter==word[cnt]:
                    list1[cnt]=user_letter
                    li=''.join(list1)
                    tag=1
                    cnt+=1
            if tag!=1:
                wrongli.extend([user_letter])
                wrong-=1
```

However this certain part of the code doest not seem to be activating as the dashes are never replace by alphabets:

```
if (not user_letter in wrongli) and (not user_letter in li):
            tag=0
            cnt=0
            x=len(word)
            while cnt<x:
                if user_letter==word[cnt]:
                    list1[cnt]=user_letter
                    li=''.join(list1)
                    tag=1
                    cnt+=1
            if tag!=1:
                wrongli.extend([user_letter])
                wrong-=1
```

Here's the full code:

```
    import os
import random
def start():

    wordlist = open("wordlist_hangman",'a+')
    words= wordlist.read().splitlines()
    choice1=menu()
    if choice1=='1':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        word=random.choice(words)
        game_start(wordlist,words,word)


    elif choice1=='2':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        add_word()
        wordlist.close()

    elif choice1=='3':
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print(words)

    else:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print('Invlaid input:must enter only 1,2 or 3 ')
    start()




def menu():
    print('Enter the number for the desired action.At any point in time use menu to go back to menu.')
    print('1.Start a new game.')
    print('2.Add words in dictionary.')
    print('3.See words present in dictionary')
    menu_choice=raw_input('>')
    return menu_choice

def game_start(game_wordlist,game_words,word):
    wrong=10
    tag=0
    cnt=0
    wrongli=[]
    while wrong>0:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print("At any point in time enter menu to return to menu.")
        print("-"*45)
        print(wrongli)
        print("-"*45)
        li='-'*len(word)
        print(li)
        user_letter=raw_input(">")
        list1=list(li)
        if (not user_letter in wrongli) and (not user_letter in li):
            tag=0
            cnt=0
            x=len(word)
            while cnt<x:
                if user_letter==word[cnt]:
                    list1[cnt]=user_letter
                    li=''.join(list1)
                    tag=1
                cnt+=1
        if tag!=1:
            wrongli.extend([user_letter])
            wrong-=1





def add_word():
    tag=0
    print("Enter the word you wish to add in your game")
    user_word=raw_input('>')
    wordlist2=open("wordlist_hangman",'a+')
    words=wordlist2.read().splitlines()
    for word in words:
        if word==user_word:
            tag=1
    if tag==1:
        print("The word already exists in dictionary")
    else:
        wordlist2.write(user_word)
    wordlist2.close
```

Comment: Not an answer but as a point of note: I believe it's more 'pythonic' to write `if x not in y`  than `if not x in y`. Also your formatting is a little off.

Comment: all right but itested each part if the code seperately(parts according to indentation) and they seem to be working fine alone

Comment: You want to debug your code. Use an actual debugger if possible, but even `print`s are enough if you do `print('user_letter:', user_letter, '\nwrongli:', wrongli, '\nli:', li)` right above your `if (not user_letter in wrongli) and (not user_letter in li):` line. See what the values actually are, is the code ever even entering the `if` block? @7h3wh173r48817

Comment: k i did that and nothing seemed to happen at first however after entering 10 wrong guesses it printed ('user_letter:', 'xv', '\nwrongli:', ['dd', 'ddd', 'a', 's', 'da', 'af', 'wr', 'avd', 'wafr'], '\nli:', '----') @MarkusMeskanen

Comment: Oh you're using Python 2, you should remove the parenthesis from the `print` and try again, so try this: `print 'user_letter:', user_letter, '\nwrongli:', wrongli, '\nli:', li`

Comment: That doesnt make much of a difference except for formatting of the text.@MarkusMeskanen

Comment: Although we can already see that `user_letter` isn't in either of them, thus your `if` should pass. Now add more prints inside the if, see what the variables' values are, find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 Yeah it was purely for the format, to make it prettier, but you shouldn't use `()` with `print` in Python 2 in your own program either

Comment: sure(learnt both python 2 and 3 so sometimes do mix it up) but anything to help with the actual problem being face here?@MarkusMeskanen

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 Add more prints inside the `if` block (and outside too, why not), see what the variables' values are, find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: they just don't print anything have already tried that.@MarkusMeskanen

Comment: @7h3wh173r48817 Add prints to other places too. If it doesn't print anything, the print is never reached. Find out where the program execution stops.

Comment: Well according to what i have experienced with my tests it doesn't execute the while block inside of if(user not in wrongli) as the part of wrong-=1(I later moved it in the if block mentioned above) does get executed however not anything I print inside the while cnt<x block.@MarkusMeskanen

Comment: One mistake I found at a quick glance: you earlier printed that `user_letter` was equal to `'xv'`, and in your code you have `if user_letter==word[cnt]:` where `cnt` is an integer. `word[cnt]` always returns *one character*, but your `user_letter` itself is two characters long, so this `if` can never be true.

Comment: that is true however i removed this part of code before posting as this didnt do anything either `while len(user_letter)!=1:
    print("Please enter only one alphabet.")
    user_letter=raw_input(">")`.@MarkusMeskanen

Comment: I don't have time right now to help you find the exact bug, sorry mate. Keep adding prints or learn how to use an actual debugger if you have to, but I'm sure you'll find it out. Add a print before *every* `if` and `while`, make sure you're aware of all values at all times. Somewhere there's an invalid value.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far but would you mind trying the code yourself i.e on your computer and see for any bugs that might help a lot. @MarkusMeskanen

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer is sort of made the dumb mistake of assigning the value of li as '-' * len(word inside the main while loop.(Silly me)